# how to display the column which is used to join the table

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: employee details table]

[image: e table]

i have two tables like this, now query is to display list of empid & name of the employees with least working hours per month id

the o/p should be like this.

```
moth_ending  Emp_id   name 
 20150131     1001    baba
 20150228     1001    baba
 20150331     1001    baba
```

i tried up to this code.

```
select Month_ending,Name,Total_workinghours
from Employee_details left join
     Dim_employee
     on Employee_details.Emp_id = Dim_employee.Emp_id
```

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 1):

Learn to use table aliases.  I think this is what you want:

```
select ed.Month_ending, ed.Emp_id, e.name
from Employee_details ed left join
     Dim_employee e
     on ed.Emp_id = e.Emp_id;
```

I don't see why a `left join` would be necessary.  If your database is properly set up then `employee_details` should refer to a valid employee.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will reach your requiremenmt.check this code and once make necessary changes in case it throws an error.

```
 ;with cte as(
       SELECT  ROW_NUMBER()over( partition by ed.MONTH_ENDING order by ed.TOTAL_WORKINGHOURS asc)as Rnum,ed.MONTH_ENDING,de.NAME,ed.TOTAL_WORKINGHOURS
    FROM    EMPLOYEE_DETAILS ed
    INNER JOIN   DIM_EMPLOYEE de
    ON ed.EMP_ID = de.DIM_EMPLOYEE.EMP_ID
    ) 
    select MONTH_ENDING,NAME,TOTAL_WORKINGHOURS from CTE where Rnum=1
```

Note:Pass the Rnum value based on requirement i.e 1,2,3..etc

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out monthwise minimum working hours first, put it in subquery and then lookup main table.

You can try following approach:

```
SELECT  ed.MONTH_ENDING,de.NAME,ed.TOTAL_WORKINGHOURS
FROM    EMPLOYEE_DETAILS ed
INNER JOIN   DIM_EMPLOYEE de
     ON ed.EMP_ID = de.DIM_EMPLOYEE.EMP_ID
WHERE (ed.MONTH_ENDING,ed.TOTAL_WORKINGHOURS)    
IN (
SELECT ed_i.MONTH_ENDING,MIN(ed_i.TOTAL_WORKINGHOURS)
FROM EMPLOYEE_DETAILS ed_i
GROUP BY ed_i.MONTH_ENDING
);
```

Answer (score 0):

with cte as(
       SELECT  ROW_NUMBER()over( partition by ed.MONTH_ENDING order by ed.TOTAL_WORKINGHOURS asc)as Rnum,ed.MONTH_ENDING,de.NAME,ed.TOTAL_WORKINGHOURS
    FROM    EMPLOYEE_DETAILS ed
    INNER JOIN   DIM_EMPLOYEE de
    ON ed.EMP_ID = de.EMP_ID
    ) 
    select MONTH_ENDING,NAME,TOTAL_WORKINGHOURS from CTE where Rnum=1